# Stop/Pause Panel while not shown in the frame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jmenubar

I'm looking for set of codes wherein the panel will pause/stop painting whenever its not shown in the frame.

I am creating a game. That whenever the first panel is in the frame the second panel pauses or stops until i clicked the New Game in the JMenuBar, then the second panel will now start. Each panel is in their respective individual classes.

Comment: `SO` does not issue sets of codes

Answer (score 2):

See [How to Write a Window Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html).

You would use the `windowDeactivated()` event to stop playing and `windowActivated()` to restart playing.

Or, as I read the question more closely you are working with panels, so you would probably use a `ContainerListener` or maybe an `AncestorListener` to handle the hiding/showing of the panels. The tutorial also has a section on using a ContainerListener. For the AncestorLIstner you can search the forum/web for examples.